# Best way to handle a NullPointerException coming from a Throwable catch? (Android)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, jit, throwable

What is the best way to handle a NullPointerException coming from a Throwable catch.

```
public void run() {
    try{

    }catch (Throwable e){

        // e.getMessage() is equal to null 
        // and sends a NullPointerException
        if (e.getMessage().equals(“something“){

        }
    }
}
```

Making some research I found [here](http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/26/hotspot-caused-exceptions-to-lose-their-stack-traces-in-production-and-the-fix/) that *the JIT compiler will optimize away stack traces in certain exceptions if they happen enough*

I thought I can throw an Exception inside the Throwable catch, but it doesn’t look clean.

Thanks!

Comment: the best way is to check if the object is actually null. Catch it, is in my opinion, *wrong  and dangerous*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write code that may throw NullPointerException.

```
public void run() {
    try {

    } catch (Throwable e){

        if (“something“.equals(e.getMessage()) {

        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public void run() {
    try {

    } catch (Throwable e){

        if (e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().equals(“something“) {

        }
    }
}
```